# Changing excel header row into date

Tags: excel, header

I have created a table in excel and from the 5th column the header must be dates like 1 Jan 23. The problem is when I create the table and  add a column to it it doesn’t increase dates by a day, it increases by a year.I tried to use fill series and changing the format but it didn’t work.
Can you please help me resolve the issue?

I changed the format to dates but it didn’t work, I also tried formula it shows the date as 00-jan-00

Comment: Your question lacks detail that makes it hard to answer. I don't know if the problem is an excel formula, an autofill, power query, or code script (i.e. python, vba).  Can you edit your question with example data. Show the problem column as it currently appears and the solution how it should appear in conceptual solution. All that might be needed is 2-4 rows.

Comment: So the first column's header in the table is a date (1 Jan 2023) but when I want to add another column for example if the date is 01 jul 2023 , the next column would become 01 jul 2024. I use the Fill series and choose to add one day to the column instead of one year but it doesn’t have any effect.

Comment: In an actual Table, headers can only be Text.

Answer (score 0):

When you mouse over the bottom right corner (red arrow) there is an icon with arrow that allows a drop down to appear. Click on the icon and select the type of fill that you want. [image]

Another option is to use a function that does a date offset an example is the end of month function.

`=EOMONTH(H1,3)` which this will be a 3 month offset. Also there is a format painter that allows you to copy the format from one location to the next clicked location. If you want to format multiple cells double click the icon then when done formatting hit the [Esc] key. [image]